# Limit FOREACH in MySQL PDO query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using the below code to try and echo out the latest 5 entries on the MySQL table, I cannot, however seem able to figure how to limit the number of results, can anyone help me out by allowing me to limit the number of results to 5 rows?

```
<table>
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/resources/pdo.php"); 
$q = "SELECT * FROM `content` ORDER BY `id`";
$query = $pdo->query($q);
$data = array_reverse($query->fetchAll());
foreach ($data as $row) {
echo "<tr><td>{$row['title']}</td><td>{$row['id']}</td></tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

Thanks!

Please note that I am new to PHP and I need help so if this question isn't useful, help me because I have only just started this.

Comment: Have you asked this to google? By the way, `LIMIT 5` will work.

Comment: Google √ IRC.PHPFREAKS √ they all gave ~ok answers but here, I found out that there should be a DESC after LIMIT 5, thanks PLB!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`order by id desc` to get rid of the array_reverse and `limit 5` to cap the number of returned results.

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM `content` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 5";
...
$data = $query->fetchAll();
```

As a global guideline: when writing queries try to formulate them in such a way that the resultset is as close to what you need as possible, ie no extra sorting or filtering operations afterwards.

1. having the dbserver send data that you aren't going to use is a waste
2. having to resort/refilter data on the webserver costs webserver performance and, in the case of big resultsets, it can cost lots of memory as well

Answer (score 4):

Use `LIMIT` clause in your SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM `content` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 5
```

From [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants (except when using prepared statements).
>
> With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):

Comment: Yes, this works: <table>
 <?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/resources/pdo.php"); 
$q = "SELECT * FROM `content` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 5";
$query = $pdo->query($q);
$data = $query->fetchAll();
//$data = array_reverse($query->fetchAll());
foreach ($data as $row) {
echo "<tr><td>{$row['title']}</td><td>{$row['id']}</td></tr>";
}
?>
</table>

Answer (score 3):

Use the LIMIT word:

```
 SELECT * FROM `content` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: thanks @ftom2 but when I do that, it isn't the last 5 rows that come up, it's the first, I want the 5 latest entries.

Comment: Your answer is close to correct but there should be a DESC, I tried all of them and that's what I concluded

Answer (score 1):

When pulling data from a database you normally set a `LIMIT` via the MySQL-query, instead of counting the loop-iterations when reading the returned data.

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM `content` ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 5";
```

Comment: Thanks but from what I have noted, it should include DESC. Thanks for the answer anyway.